# How does File System monitoring works in theory?

Tags: file, filesystems, operating-system, monitoring, monitor

I'm working paper about remote file synchronization (just like Dropbox). However I'm having problems finding information about how the OS File System (FS) sends file events (or how are them generated and based on what (FS logs?))

I know that there are plenty of tools like: java7 WatchService or C# FileSystemWatcher, but I what to understand how they get such information.

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me some articles or books to look for.

Thanks

Comment: missing "does" at question :P

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11687685/edit) by clicking on the edit link below your question.

Answer (score 1):

Start with inotify first.  It is what Linux uses, and is very well-documented.

[Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) is a great article by Robert Love that will give you an basic architectural overview with code examples.